# Post callback not getting called

Tags: angular

I'm doing a save via my service and it is saving fine:

```
this.generalService.saveAllGameData(this.gameData).subscribe(
            data => {

                console.log(data);
                
                this.deleteUnrequiredFilesOnSave();
                this.notifyService.changeNotify("Saved!");
                this.router.navigate(["/rooms"]);

            },
            error => {

            },
            () => {

                console.log("Posted!");

            }
            );
```

And here's the code in the service:

```
saveAllGameData(newData: any): Observable<any> {
        const body = newData;
        return this.http.post("" + this.apiDomain() + "/api/gameCentre", body)
    }
```

But all the stuff inside the data callback doesn't get called. Any ideas why?
Even the `console.log("Posted!");` doesn't action.

Comment: What is the type of response from the API? Is it a JSON object?

Comment: @MichaelD I just send a string back saying "success" pretty basic. But even the stuff inside () => {} isn't getting called for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the comment, most probably the callbacks aren't being triggered due to lack of correct response type in the request.

Try the following

```js
saveAllGameData(newData: any): Observable<any> {
  const body = newData;
  return this.http.post(
    "" + this.apiDomain() + "/api/gameCentre", 
    body, 
    { responseType: 'text' }
  );
}
```

The default `responseType` is `'json'`.

Comment: Yes this worked thanks. It's strange I understand why the data => would fail to be called. But I reckon the ()=> still should have responded as it's not based on getting a response.

Comment: Yes it is weird that it doesn't throw any error. But if the `HttpClient` tries to interpret the response as a JSON object and if it's not, the execution is stopped at that line. It doesn't proceed forward.